Windows Server 2019 IIS with AAR will forward from a desktop but not mobile device
I have a web server running on a LAMP server using Oracle Linux 8, Apache 2.4.  It is reverse proxied from a  Windows Server 2019, using Microsoft ARR and URL Rewrite.
It works great if the client is a desktop Windows or Mac OS.  However if the client is a mobile device, iPad (Using Safari or Chrome), or an Android tablet (Google Chrome), it does not forward the connection to the LAMP server and either takes the client to the default website on the IIS box (with HTTP), or gives an error that the directory is not found or they do not have the correct permissions (with HTTPS).
I have tried everything I can find on the web, such as disabling HTTP/2 (both with the registry values, and checking disable HTTP/2 in the default site bindings).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It sounds like you have some conditional rewrites happening either in IIS or the applications on IIS. They will be defined either in a web.config (root or a subdirectory), or in the applicationhost.config if its IIS. Failed Request tracing module might help log more details, as might the HTTPERR log and the IIS application access logs (inetpub\logs). Also check Event Viewer Application Logs - the issue could still be code related so any application specific logs should be viewed as well. Edit your question and add further detail (make sure to remove any sensitive values from your config)

I fixed the issue with the Android tablets.  There was a binding to another server on the default website.  However still broken for iOS devices.  I found this fix for the same issue with NGINX.  How would i add the following arguments for ARR?
Continued in next comment.

proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests";
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Cache-Control "no-transform" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer always;
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

You can set custom headers in the web.config/IIS manager. Take a look at as a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/

Cool Sir, I believe I actually have this working!

Not going to worry about it right now, but it is strange.  (Strange that it works on all other devices but iOS.  So going to the root "www.catracing.org" Which has a URL rewrite on the apache server to go to www.catracing.org/hendrb.  If I use the full url, it routes fine!  I would say it is an apache problem, but without ARR, (have the router send all requests to the LINUX BOX). It works fine.  My work around was to put a URL redirect on the default website.  Not elegant, not fixed, but a passable workaround right now.
